# Como puedo modificar datos un registro con punteros en C?

Tags: c, funciones, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

En mi programa tengo un registro **struct** *alumnos* donde ingreso datos de 3 alumnos, (*nombre, edad, telefono*), en el programa principal (**main**) se pregunta que desea hacer, al seleccionar la opción "modificar", necesito modificar algún valor ingresado, pero en una *funcion* aparte, son 3 funciones en total y solo llegué a completar una

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define n 3


    struct alumno{

        char nombre[20];
        int edad;
        int telefono;
    }alum[n];

    int main(){

        int opcion,i;
        struct alumno*punt;
        punt=alum;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("alumno; %d",i+1);
            printf("\n");
            printf("ingrese nombre ");
            scanf("%s",(punt+i)->nombre);
            printf("ingrese edad ");
            scanf("%d",&(punt+i)->edad);
            printf("ingrese telefono ");
            scanf("%d",&(punt+i)->telefono);
        }
        printf("1_dar de alta 2_modificar registro 3_buscar el alumno mayor");
        scanf("%d",&opcion);

        switch(opcion){

            case 1: alta(punt);
                    break;
            case 2: modificar(punt);
                    break;
            case 3:mayor(punt);
                    break;
        }  
    }

    void alta(struct alumno *p){

        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(strcmp((p+i)->nombre,"")==0){
                printf("nombre : ");
                scanf("%s",(p+i)->nombre);
                printf("edad : ");
                scanf("%d",(p+i)->edad);
                printf("telefono : ");
                scanf("%d",&(p+i)->telefono);
            }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué usas la etiqueta `c#`?. En dicho lenguaje el uso de punteros es totalmente distinto al de `C`. Además deberías mostrar el código que has escrito y señalar de manera más clara cuál es tu problema.

Comment: ahí lo corregí, mi error

Comment: ¿ Quieres que te hagamos nosotros las funciones `modificar( )` y `mayor( )` ? ¿ Completas ? Voto por cerrarla.